# align absolute position element to right and keep it responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css

html

```
<div id="navBar">
    <div class="navBarStyles">
        <ul class="navBarInfo">
            <li><a href="#" class="i-icon iconStyles">u</a>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Advertise</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="mainNavBar">
            <li><a href="#" class="menu-icon iconStyles">z</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">WORKS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ARTICLES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>       
        <div style="clear: both"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
li{
    list-style: none;
}
#navBar{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #0088FF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

@media only screen
        and (max-width : 500px) {
            #navBar .menu-icon{
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
            }
            #navBar .i-icon{
                float: right;
            }
            #navBar .navBarStyles{
                position: relative;
            }
            #navBar .navBarStyles li ul{
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                display: block;
                margin: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }
            #navBar .navBarStyles li ul li{
                display: inline-block;
                margin-left: -4.08px;
                width: 33.333333333333333333333333333333%;
            }
            #navBar .navBarStyles li ul li a{
                display: block;
            }
            #navBar .navBarStyles li ul{
                display: none;
            }
        }
```

Please bear with me as I've included a bit long code (just for better understading) for a small problem, What I would like to do is move `z` to the right to position is to the left of `u`. Similar to the screenshot below.

[image]

The problem is with the markup, as the list items are under those two buttons (`z & u`), so the list below that displays when links clicked is being disposition. I have tried `float: right` on the element as well by changing the markup. But still the same problem. I want the list below to displayed as it is now when clicked just want to change the position of the `z` button. Thanks for any helpt!

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5sFxd/)

how elements below should be displayed

---

[image: how elements below should be displayed]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this :

```
#navBar .navBarInfo {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
#navBar .mainNavBar {
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
}
```

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/x8BD3/)

[EDIT]

Here is updated version as requested/explained in comment:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/U3G94/)

Comment: this destroys the position of the list items below.

Comment: And how exactly would you like yours sub menus to be aligned / displayed ?

Comment: added screen shot above. Those display fine for now.

Comment: You need to change the structure of the html to accomplish something like that .. I've attached in my answer second JSFIDDLE example showing how. If that's not an option, then you need to update that structure with jQuery on document.ready and make it similar.

Comment: thanks! BTW, I was to transfer the `z` button to right but not swap the both.